# Wifi not working Ubuntu 16.04 after update

Tags: 16.04, wireless

I Desktop on Thursday last week:
Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
Core i5 6500+8GB RAM+ ASUS H170 PRO Gaming MB
After that the Wifi on my Desktop has stopped working while in Secure boot mode.

The Wifi adapter on my desktop is: TP-Link TL-WN735N

Output of lsusb command:

```
    aditya@Aditya-ASUS:~$ lsusb
    Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
    Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
    Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
    Bus 001 Device 003: ID 10c4:8105 Cygnal Integrated Products, Inc. 
    Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0bda:8179 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
    RTL8188EUS 802.11n Wireless Network Adapter
    Bus 001 Device 004: ID 046d:c31c Logitech, Inc. Keyboard K120
    Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

The Wifi works if I disable Secure Boot.
Is there any way to make the Wifi work in Secure boot mode.
Exactly what should I do?

Comment: Please ask one question regarding each of your computers. But in this case it does not look very likely that both stopped working simultaneously. Do non-Ubuntu devices work with this AP?

Comment: Yes sir, they do. Basically both work in Windows while secure boot enables. I actually just tried disabling secure boot on my Desktop, and suddenly my Wifi worked. Will be trying on my laptop too. Any way to make the wifi work without disabling Secure boot?

Comment: Also, I generally update my laptop and my Desktop every two days, if there are any updates. After the wifi stopped working, though, I had put the updates on hold.

Comment: [Edit] the question and leave only one computer. Then we can proceed in finding out what has happened. I suggest starting with the second one.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lsusb` terminal command.

Comment: Hello, so I edited the question. basically my wifi is working if Secure Boot is disabled. Any way to make it work in Secure Boot mode? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You installed a 3rd party driver to get the USB adapter working.

Secure Boot does not let unsigned kernel modules load.

I suggest keeping the Secure Boot disabled if you are using unsigned modules. This feature is useless.

It is possible to sign the module and put the signature into UEFI. It is also possible to make a script that will automatically sign modules on DKMS updates.

But it is very complex and is not worth the effort.

Comment: OK, sure thanks. just to ask, is there any downside to keeping secure boot disabled as long as I am not booting another OS other than those installed: Ubuntu and Windows 8.1+ 10?

Comment: See also http://askubuntu.com/questions/762254/why-do-i-get-required-key-not-available-when-install-3rd-party-kernel-modules

Comment: @Aditya There is no downside. The SB does not really protect from any existing threat. It makes problems for other OS's except Windows. That was the whole idea of it.

Comment: So, basically disabling Secure Boot poses no problem? Thanks a lot for your Help!

Comment: I would recommend that you disable secure boot and set an administrative password to your BIOS. This way you can also make it request the passphrase when a non-standard storafe medium is used to initiate boot (such as a live CD). As long as you password protect your bootable devices list and BIOS, disabling secure boot should have no negative consequences